# Is there a program (like Filezilla) to transfer files by schedule to the Raspberry Pi?

Tags: raspbian, tftp

I have been trying to find a replacement to [FileZilla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileZilla) which is a good program, but it doesn't allow yet to schedule files to transfer from time to time. I run into some, but they are all supported by Windows, ([WinSCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WinSCP) and [FTP Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTP_Voyager)). Is there something like that, or does it have to be made by scripting?

I have Raspbian Debian 7 (Wheezy) installed.

Script to be executed with cron:

```
cd /home/website/.wine/dosdevices/c:/_Auchan/_path
smbclient //sanfiler01.corp.pt.auchan/FTP_Externo -D "WEBSITE/_Auchan/_SOMETHING/" -U "corpauchanpt\sup_website" AKne123! -c "prompt; mget *; exit"
```

Changed to:

```
cd /var/www/LRD/musica/easy
smbclient //website.pt/FTP_Externo -D "website/xv01ZT/01/" -U corpauchanpt\sup_website" AKne123! -c "prompt; mget *; exit"
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/). It supports incremental file transfer, and you can schedule your backups with cron or any other scheduling tool.

Comment: Well, rsync won't do the scheduling, you'd need Windows tasks or `cron` for that.

Comment: Rsync with `at` could work,  too.

Comment: Thanks for all the support so far. I have been trying to get Crontab to work for hours, but without success. Used `cp` `cp -r` `cp -rf` even tried within the RPi from a folder to another, it never worked. I checked the paths, they seem to be fine, I dont understand what could i be doing wrong.

Comment: Ok, got it to work, it was a simple matter of path being missing the root folders `/home/pi` normally they are not necessary but, since then it has worked. Although I still can't do it locally. I'm using a script now, with instructions of `samba` and to be executed with `crontab`. My tutor gave me a script he had from a linux computer to transfer files at a certain time, and im supposed to convert it to use in raspberry pi. I think it´s probably a matter of changing paths, but io´m not sure it will still work. I'll edit the question with that*

Answer (score 1):

Why not use FileZilla? The GUI doesn't support scheduled operations, but you can do that with cron/windows scheduled tasks and the command line.  The last example on the documentation page even explains how to use saved machines/credentials.

Example:

`filezilla ftp://username:password@ftp.server2.com --local="C:\server2 downloads"`

Example with different paths and sftp instead of ftp:

`filezilla sftp://username:password@192.168.0.3:22/directory_path_here -- local="/home/pi/directory/file"`

Documentation: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Command-line_arguments_(Client)

Comment: But does it only work with windows/cron? Because I have Raspbian as my OS. That line of code would not work in this case

Comment: @angelfmf: I wasn't sure what operating system you needed the automation on.  This would work both on a Windows machine using `Task Scheduler`, and on Raspbian using `cron`

Comment: @angelfmf: example added

Comment: That is good news, can you show me an example of how to change the path. Would this work? `filezilla ftp://username:password@ftp.mywebsite  --localhost/LRD/something` Don't know what 0 means. Sorry i sent the before comment by mistake.

Comment: I think the --localhost argument needs an = before the path and " around the path.  Other than that, I can't really be sure without trying it on your machines' configurations.  Try plugging it into the terminal and see if it works :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the replies, they were very helpful although i get an error saying bash: filezilla: command not found. I think it is because i have to install filezilla on the raspberry as well.

Comment: Yes, my apologies. I thought you were already using filezilla through the graphical interface. `sudo apt-get update -y ; sudo apt-get install filezilla`

Comment: No, it's ok, it was my fault for not realizing that before executing the code line. I already did it, and it gives another error this time. Unknown long option. I have been searching but i can´t find anything explaining that error

Comment: @angelfmf: long options are things that start with `--`.  make sure things are spelled correctly and the `=` is present?

Comment: I verified every word and they seem to be all right. Also changed from --local to -local and got this error `logontype, can only be used together with FTP URL. Argument has to be either 'ask' or 'interactive'` it is like this `filezilla sftp://username:password@ip:port/directory_path --local="/home/pi/..."`

Comment: The `--local` argument doesn't work, it must be depricated, i also tried with other options but they won't work. i have to search for another option of transfering files with cron, doesn't seem that filezilla will work

Answer (score 1):

Try [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io/?l=en). I use this to access the Raspberry PI files. Easy to use and free.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But although it is for the Linux system it doesn't have the auto-tranfer feature, does it? I´m trying to use filezilla together with cron following instructions from Jacobm001 but haven't succeded yet. Can't get past some errors.